# Divi: custom menu item doesn't work properly (text color)

Tags: css, divi

I use Divi for my website (based on Wordpress).

When the scroll of the page is on top, all is perfect, the text color of the "Se connecter" button is white (OK):

[image]

But, when I scroll, this color change like other items menu... I want to stay white color for this custom item menu, all the time.

[image]

For this custom item menu, I use this CSS:

```
.menu_cta {
    background-color: #157FFB;
    color: #fff;
    padding: 0 !important;
    border-radius: 5px;
}

.menu_cta a {
    color: #fff !important;
    padding: 8px 13px 8px 13px !important;
    border-radius: 5px;
}

.menu_cta:hover {
    background-color: #106CD6;
}
```

Comment: Share Website url Please @anthony

Comment: Sorry I can't it's for a client, it's impossible now (it's in a staging mode).